# Flex: Could not create

Tags: windows, flex-lexer

I've used flex with cygwin and it worked just fine, so I've installed flex for windows because I need a windows version of my program. When I tried to create the lexer I got the message:

```
flex: could not create.
```

Here's the file (it works with cygwin):

```
%{
  #include "Ast.h"
  #include "Parser.hpp"
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <string>
  #define SAVE_TOKEN_STR yylval.string = new std::string(yytext, yyleng)
  #define TOKEN(t) (yylval.token = t)
%}
%%
[0-9]+                                      { SAVE_TOKEN_STR; return INTEGER; }
[0-9]+\.[0-9]+                              { SAVE_TOKEN_STR; return FLOAT; }
[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?[eE][-+]?[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)? { SAVE_TOKEN_STR; return SCIENTIFIC; }
"("    { return TOKEN(LPAR); }
")"    { return TOKEN(RPAR); }
"{"    { return TOKEN(LCBR); }
"}"    { return TOKEN(RCBR); }
"["    { return TOKEN(LSQBR); }
"]"    { return TOKEN(RSQBR); }
"+"    { return TOKEN(PLUS); }
"-"    { return TOKEN(MINUS); }
"*"    { return TOKEN(STAR); }
"/"    { return TOKEN(SLASH); }
"%"    { return TOKEN(PERCENT); }
"**"   { return TOKEN(EXPONENT); }
"="    { return TOKEN(ASSIGN); }
"=="   { return TOKEN(EQ); }
"<>"   { return TOKEN(NEQ); }
"<"    { return TOKEN(LESS); }
"<="   { return TOKEN(LOE); }
"<=>"  { return TOKEN(SPACESHIP); }
">"    { return TOKEN(GREATER); }
">="   { return TOKEN(GOE); }
"!"    { return TOKEN(NOT); }
"&&"   { return TOKEN(AND); }
"||"   { return TOKEN(OR); }
"not"  { return TOKEN(NOT); }
"and"  { return TOKEN(AND); }
"or"   { return TOKEN(OR); }
"~"    { return TOKEN(BITWISE_NOT); }
"&"    { return TOKEN(BITWISE_AND); }
"|"    { return TOKEN(BITWISE_OR); }
"^"    { return TOKEN(BITWISE_XOR); }
"<<"   { return TOKEN(BITWISE_LSHIFT); }
">>"   { return TOKEN(BITWISE_RSHIFT); }
"~~"   { return TOKEN(ROUND); }
"."    { return TOKEN(DOT); }
".."   { return TOKEN(RANGE); }
"..."  { return TOKEN(TRANGE); }
"?"    { return TOKEN(QUESTION_MARK); }
":"    { return TOKEN(COLON); }
"in"   { return TOKEN(IN); }
","    { return TOKEN(COMMA); }
[A-Za-z_][A-Za-z0-9_]*    { SAVE_TOKEN_STR; return IDENT; }
[ \n\t] ;
.      { printf("Illegal token!\n"); yyterminate(); }
%%
#ifndef yywrap
  yywrap() { return 1; }
#endif
```

And here's the command I'm trying to execute:

```
flex -o Lexer.l Lexer.cpp
```

In cygwin the only difference is that I need to switch up the source and destionation file names in the command.

Edit:

If I try:

```
flex -o Lexer.cpp Lexer.l
```

I get:

```
flex: can't open Lexer.cpp
```

Comment: Does it really produce the error message `flex: could not create.` like that, with a period immediately following the word `create`?

Comment: Yes, this is the exact output

Comment: Well, that is odd. The format string is "could not create %s", which has a space and does not have a `.`. Because of the peculiar argument parsing strategy, the filename is the empty string, so I'd expect the error message to be `could not create `, with an invisible space at the end. But that's just a little detail, I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
flex -o Lexer.l Lexer.cpp
```

tells flex to process the input file `Lexer.cpp`, and put the *output* (`-o`) in `Lexer.l`. I'm guessing that that is not what you wanted to do, since normally `Lexer.l` would be the input and it would be undesirable to overwrite it.

On really old versions of flex (and `flex 2.5.4a`, as used by "flex for windows", counts as a really old version), you cannot put a space after the `-o`; the filename must immediately follow the letter `o`. So the correct command line is:

```
flex -oLexer.cpp Lexer.l
```

---

By the way,

```
#include "Ast.h"
#include "Parser.hpp"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
```

is really not good style. Normally, system (library) headers should be `#include`d first, and normally with C++ you would use `#include <cstdio>` rather than the C header `stdio.h`. But that's not relevant to your question.

Comment: On windows this is the other way around. If I flex -o Lexer.cpp Lexer.l, I get: flex: can't open Lexer.cpp

Comment: @PeterLenkefi: what is the version of flex on your Windows machine? I assure you that any version of flex which interprets the `-o` option will treat it as meaning "put the output into the file whose name follows."

Comment: @PeterLenkefi: Updated the answer based on that version number. Please edit your original question to include that information, since it is relevant.

Comment: Gosh, that was the problem. Thanks